# subprocess.call and ending current program

Tags: python, subprocess

My main program checks if a new version of itself is available and if so it downloads the new installer file and runs it:
`subprocess.call(["installer.exe"], shell=True)`
But in order to overwrite the old files, it needs to exit itself after calling the subprocess. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, just `start` your installer program instead of waiting for it.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["start","installer.exe"],shell=True)
print("out")
```

Running this will print `out` immediately and returns to the console if this is the last statement (or call `sys.exit()`)